# javascript array with key

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

I want to get the JSON from an array with this format

```
[
  {
    "title": "Name"
  },
  {
    "title": "Phone"
  },
  {
    "title": "Parent Phone"
  },
  {
    "title": "Street"
  }
]
```

I tried this code:

```
var favorite = new Array();
$.each($("#db_fields"), function() {
    var field = {
        'title': $(this).val()
    };
    favorite.push(field);
});
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(favorite);
alert(myJsonString);
```

`$("#db_fields")` is a select (Bootstrap-select), it's an array of string

```
<select class="form-control"  name="db_fields[]" id="db_fields" data-live-search="true" multiple >
        <option value="Arabic Name"> Arabic Name</option>
        <option value="Building"> Building</option>
</select>
```

but I got this result

```
[{"title":["Arabic Name","Phone","Building","Nationality"]}]
```

Comment: Please post the JSON data.

Comment: What is the content of `$("#db_fields")`?

Comment: `$.each()` with (only) an id should ring all your alarm bells as ids have to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the ***options*** of the `select` (`"#db_fields > option"`) tag:

```js
var favorite = [];
$.each($("#db_fields > option"), function(){   
        let field = {
            'title': this.value
        };
        favorite.push(field);
});
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(favorite);
console.log(myJsonString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control"  name="db_fields[]" id="db_fields" data-live-search="true" multiple >
        <option value="Arabic Name"> Arabic Name</option>
        <option value="Building"> Building</option>
</select>
```